# Jquery change selected option trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am having troubles with `<select options>` tags in HTML.

I am trying to change the value of the select dropdown using jQuery and Javascript so that I can do something in AJAX calls using the selected value of the dropdown. However, upon changing that and then I would like to revert back to the old value that I have selected before changing it, there are problems that arise... I can still pick/select values from the dropdown options, but the value displayed in the `<select option>` button/form box is the last value that I have placed there.

Is there a way for me to fix this? Here is my code below.

```
//retrieving value of the selected option
var selBlock = $("#block_name option:selected").text();

//changing the value of the selected option from the dropdown to the very first option
$("#block_name").change(function() {
    $("#block_name option:first").attr('selected','selected');  
}).change();

//changing back the value of the selected option on the dropdown by reverting to the old value saved in selBlock

$("#block_name").change(function(){
    $("#block_name").find('option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
    document.getElementById('block_name').value = selBlock;
}).change();
```

This is a way for me to achieve a real-time effect by simply changing the options selected in the dropdown, since changing it will invoke an AJAX call and retrieve new values from the database. I choose not to use SSE or AJAX long polling since I know that it will stress our server.

Comment: There are a couple things wrong: 1) you are binding to the change event for the same element twice and countering what the other bind is doing, 2) you are then firing the change immediately after you bound the change event, 3) you are overriding any select changed value so that there would be no ability to ever select anything from the select list other than the first option anyway. Beyond all that, you probably should not be using jQuery to change the value for an ajax call, you should be using whatever value the user chooses: $("#block_name").val() will work.

Answer (score 0):

If I get the idea of what you're doing:

- Rather than get the `text` of the selected `option`, go for the `value` of the `select` element
- Instead of defining change event handlers (2) change the value and then `trigger` the event

Here is how the code should look like:

```
//Save your DOM search so you don't have to repeat it
var sel = $("#block_name");

//retrieve value of the selected option
var selBlock = sel.val();

//change the value of the selected option from the dropdown to the very first option 
//& trigger change
sel.find('option:first').prop('selected', true).end().trigger( 'change' );

//change back the value of the selected option on the dropdown by reverting to
// the old value saved in selBlock & trigger change event
sel.val( selBlock ).trigger( 'change' );
```